# Formatting Label Content Font

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've been trying to change the `FontWeight` of a single `Label` inside of a `StackPanel` of labels to no avail. In the example below, I try to change the `FontWeight` inline with the `Label` definition, but this does not work. I can't seem to change the `FontWeight`, `FontSize`, `FontStyle`, etc. I have been able to change the `Foreground` though.

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            DataContext="{Binding Path=MyDataContext}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" >
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Label1Content}" FontWeight="Bold"></Label>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Label2Content}"></Label>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Label3Content}" ContentStringFormat="c"></Label>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Label4Content}" ContentStringFormat="c"></Label>
</StackPanel>
```

I have also tried creating a resource and using a style to do it and have tried changing the `FontWeight` using the code behind, neither worked.

Comment: Can you give more information about what doesn't work on your side? I just created an empty WPF project with a Label defined like yours and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: What does the WPF debugger's Live Property Inspector window tell you?

Comment: @Dai the debugger says it's bold, but it is not showing up as bold. Same thing happens if I change the FontSize, FontStyle, etc.

Comment: @TorbenJ it just doesn't display as bold, the text is no different

Comment: Does this only happen in the project this code belongs to? Do you have any style that applies to Label control globally that override FontWeights in some way?

Comment: Well global styles shouldn't have any effect though, tried it and the FontWeight defined on the element itself should override anything else. Makes sense though I don't know if there are any edge cases where this doesn't apply. Was just a thought

Comment: @TorbenJ there is a global FontWeight, but if I click on the Label in Visual Studio it shows that it is bold in the debugger, so I figured that meant it was overriding it. If it's working for you in a fresh project, then it has to be something specific in my project that I'm overlooking, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further looking in the Live Property Inspector, even though the `Label` was bold, there was a `TextBlock` inside that was not. Changing the labels to the following code fix this:

```
<Label>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label1Content}" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
</Label>
```